# Espectrograma ao contrário

Tags: python

Estou tentando plotar um espectrograma com os dados que me foram fornecidos, contudo, o resultado parece "invertido". Alguém já passou pela mesma situacao?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O frame em que o sinal aparece corresponde com o meu sinal original, só nao entendo por quê está ao contrario.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
D = librosa.amplitude_to_db(np.abs(librosa.stft(data))) 
librosa.display.specshow(D)
librosa.display.specshow(D,x_axis='time',y_axis='linear',sr=sample_rate,cmap='plasma')
plt.savefig('spectrum.png', format='png', dpi=600)
```

Comment: invertido significa que os eixos x e y estão trocados?

Comment: ou de cabeça para baixo?

Comment: as linhas estao horizontais para cima, deveriam estar na vertical,"andando" para a direita nao?